# Swift: How to change the language inside of the app?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app with localized string files.
[Here are what my localized string files look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl3WX.png).
I also have a tableView with cells containing accessoryType (check marks). I want to let the user change the language of my app when changing the check in the tableView.
Here are the codes I have in the tableView of the settings of the app:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.setValues(value: languageArray[indexPath.row]) // Upload new language settings to the server

    // Here I want to set the language of my app to the selected value: languageArray[indexPath.row]
    // For example, languageArray[indexPath.row] is "en"

    var array = tableView.visibleCells

    for i in 0 ..< array.count {
        let cells: UITableViewCell = array[i]
        cells.accessoryType = .none
    }

    let cell:UITableViewCell! = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but this strikes me as a very bad idea.  For example, if you find a way to do it, are you going to change it back when you exit?  What about when you go to the background?  What about a crash?  Please let the user use standard controls for things when those exist.

Answer (score 13):

As most of answer saying "this is not possible" **but**,

**It is possible** and can be done it by simple thing.

In `iOS` application there are bundle for each languages, like `en.lproj` for english. You just need to load that specific bundle from selected language and get localizable stuff like: string, images etc. from this bundle.

```
    var selectedLanguage = "en"
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: selectedLanguage, ofType: "lproj")
    let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
    let localizedText = bundle!.localizedString(forKey: YOUR_TEXT_KEY, value: YOUR_TEXT_COMMENT, table: nil)
```

For reference, i cerated an [LanguageDemo](https://github.com/rockyy/LanguageDemo) app, you can found all implementation and complete source code.

Comment: how to use this language demo in the storyboard instead of coding! I mean how to localize the storyboard with this method

Comment: @Am1rFT You have to set your strings programatically

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to do it, but as the previous answers mentioned it's not the best idea and might no be approved by Apple app review. But here is what I've tried and it worked:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(["en"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Whenever the user select the language you need to apply this code, just replace ["en"] with your selected language. Keep in mind the user need to exit the app in order for this to work properly.

Answer (score 4):

I know "this is not possible" answers are not really popular in Stack Overflow, but anyhow..

**What you want to do is not possible.** iOS doesn't allow you to change the language of the app from within the app. There is no API for that, and even if you somehow manage to achieve this thing by hacking (monkey patching) iOS, Apple wouldn't allow your app to be published to the itunes store.

There is a language setting within the "Settings" app (a system app), and there the user can set the language. All installed apps will use this language setting.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to change the language of the iphone, but if you just want to change your app's language, I think there is the way: you can save the map as a plist or json file but the system `.strings`. And do not use the func `NSLocalizedString`, just encapsulation a func to get it, all the thing will be on the control.

Answer (score 0):

This is so untrue about publishing etc, there is a way and you are not hacking anything, it is true there is not api for that but it is only a few lines of code, and it is nothing complicated... http://aplus.rs/2017/in-app-language-change-in-ios-app/ 
there is the link for your question, we have that o0n academy and this guy is our professor, if there is something you don't understand i am glad to help you with this because i got the same problem 2 years a go...

Comment: one more time apple doesn’t give a sheet about what you do to change in app language ... we published 2 apps with this functionality...
you do not need to exit app will restart its self with this through appdelegate